# RoR Controller accessed from two different link_to buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, link-to

I have a Controller whose New action is being accessed from two different nav-bar links. The reason for this is that the same Controller is required for two different functions.
How can I pass some params to make the Controller know from which link_to it was accessed? (So that I can modify the new.html.erb file slightly)

Answer (score 0):

Since the controller's `new` action is being rendered, it means that you must be rendering a form. In this form you could pass a hidden field like so:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :value_name, :value => "true" %>
```

Now in your Controller's `create` action you can check before saving like this:

```
def create
 if params[:model_name][:value_name] == true
   # then it must have come from first nav link,hence save that
else  
  # the value has come from the other nav.
end
end
```

You must also make the value `false` when you're clicking on the second nav link, like so:

```
<%= link_to "ABC", resource_path(:value_name => "false") %>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. But the rendering of the form should be different depending on which link was clicked to create it. I need to pass some sort of params from the link itself. As a last resort, I may have to add a column to the resource and then pass different values for the new column through  the two links. But is there a way to avoid adding a useless attribute?

Comment: I don't think so, if that is the use case a simple Boolean column could save you from mangling the rest of the code.

Comment: Thanks again. Doing that.